# Indexeddb Encrypt Data offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encryption, indexeddb

I need to know, which is the better way that encrypt data when I am using indexeddb. I want to encrypt data offline. This project is application with reactjs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Questions about picking the better way may be seen as opinion based questions, but they can usually be reworded to avoid that problem.